# Hibernate: Retrieve distance value from spatial search

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, geospatial, hibernate-search

I'm trying to retrieve a list of shops within the radius of the user's current location using Hibernate Spatial. I want to provide the distance to the user along with each result without calculating the distance twice.

Hibernate's [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.3/reference/en-US/html/ch09.html#spatial-queries-distance) suggests setting a projection to the FullTextQuery in order to include the distance in the results. However, the example provides no indication of how to retrieve said value. The example simply ends up retrieving a list of shops within the radius but not the distance to the center.

This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```java
FullTextSession session = (FullTextSession)Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
QueryBuilder builder = session.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Shop.class).get();

Query query = builder.spatial()
        .onField("location")
        .within(radius, Unit.KM)
            .ofLatitude(latitude)
            .andLongitude(longitude)
        .createQuery();

FullTextQuery hibernate = session.createFullTextQuery(query)
        .setProjection(FullTextQuery.SPATIAL_DISTANCE, FullTextQuery.THIS)
        .setSpatialParameters(latitude, longitude, "location");

// TODO: build map of shops and their distance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distances are included in the query hit, in an object array, just like any other projection.

```
FullTextSession session = (FullTextSession)Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
QueryBuilder builder = session.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Shop.class).get();

Query query = builder.spatial()
        .onField("location")
        .within(radius, Unit.KM)
            .ofLatitude(latitude)
            .andLongitude(longitude)
        .createQuery();

FullTextQuery ftQuery = session.createFullTextQuery(query, Shop.class)
        .setProjection(FullTextQuery.SPATIAL_DISTANCE, FullTextQuery.THIS)
        .setSpatialParameters(latitude, longitude, "location");

List<Object[]> results = ftQuery.list();
Object[] firstResult = results.get(0);
Double distance = (Double) firstResult[0];
Shop shop = (Shop) firstResult[1];
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. The lack of generics confused me, I thought the List would again be List<Shop>.

Comment: Yep, it's confusing. For what it's worth, Hibernate Search 6 solved that with a new API: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-distance , https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-composite